# Hefsek during kaddish and shemonah Esrei

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, hefsek-interruption

Here's the case: In the shul I daven mincha in during the week, the chazzan is stopped nearly daily by the rav, either in the middle of the kaddish recited after ashrei or in the middle of Shemonah Esrei, because the tzibbur is talking; then he continues.

My question is as follows: Is the chazzan allowed to stop at these points? Is stopping during kaddish different than stoping during the repetition of shemonah Esrei? What would be some of the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Halacha we find that stopping during the recital Shma (a Torah obligation) - even long enough to finish the entire reading (according to some opinions) - is permitted. (הלכות קרית שמע פרק ב' הלכה י"ב)

We also find cases where one should stop one's recital of the Amida and remain silent. E.g. when Kadish or Kedusha is being recited.

So we see that there's no real problem for silent breaks during davening.

Especially if the silent breaks are made to get the congregation to stop talking - a major sin if done during prayers. All the more so during חזרת הש"ץ when 9 people have to be answering אמן else the ש"ץ is making Brachot in vain.

Comment: Your first paragraph is just one opinion in one case. http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x435 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x470

Comment: @DoubleAA - Edited as per your comment.